# Django : difference between calling self.model.save() and self.model.save(*args,**kwargs)

Tags: python, django, orm

Is there a difference between calling a model's save like :

`self.model.save(*args,**kwargs)`

and:

`self.model.save()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious difference is that in the first case you are passing positional and keyword arguments. If you wonder what arguments `Model.save()` takes and what they do, the simplest thing is to read the source code. Then you'll find something like:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    """
    Saves the current instance. Override this in a subclass if you want to
    control the saving process.

    The 'force_insert' and 'force_update' parameters can be used to insist
    that the "save" must be an SQL insert or update (or equivalent for
    non-SQL backends), respectively. Normally, they should not be set.
    """
    if force_insert and force_update:
        raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.")
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
```

The third argument, `using`, is not documented, it specifies which db connection you want to use (if you have more than one db connection).

To make a long story short:

- when you want to save your instance (in a view or form or whatever), you usually just want to let Django handle all this so you call `my_model_instance.save()` without arguments
- when you override the `save` method in your Model class, you definitly want to accept **and** pass the same arguments when calling on the base class `save`, ie:

  class MyModel(models.Model):
      def save(self, *args, **kw):
          do_something_here()
          super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
          do_something_else()